# vue-cli webpack precedence of styles

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, vue.js, sass

I have a problem with vue webpack scaffolding from the vue cli regarding the way it handles style scope in dev and prod
in a component I have:

```
<div class=input-group><input class="form-control someformcontrol" ...

<style lang="sass" scoped>
.someformcontrol
    z-index:0
```

and my project uses **bootstrap-sass**.

with `npm run dev` I get

```
. someformcontrol[data-v-2929f1fc] {
    z-index: 0;
}
.input-group .form-control {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

that is, both a local component style and the bootstrap sass style are loaded up, but the local style overrides the bootstrap style.

but with `npm run prod` I get the order reversed:

```
.input-group .form-control {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
. someformcontrol[data-v-2929f1fc] {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

in other words, run locally, I get z-index of 0 because the scoped component style overrides bootstrap sass
but that same thing with npm run build has the orders reversed and the effective z-index becmoes 2 (and the effect is that **I can't override bootstrap sass in scoped component tags with `npm run prod`**). I'm not sure what to look for in `build/` to address this.